# navigationview with different toolbar for each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar, android-navigationview

I'm implementing a `navigationview` in an `Activity`.When a navigationview item gets clicked a new fragment starts.My toolbar is defined in Activity and the problem is that i want to use different toolbars for each fragment.For example in one fragment the toolbar will contain a spinner, on another a couple of textviews etc.

What are my options here?I've thought of keeping the toolbar on Activity and inflate afterwards the views i need from fragment, but maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a very similar question here:

[How to use different Toolbars on each Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35469802/5914610)

It's basically all about:

1) Creating 1 XML for each different Toolbar

2) Including them on your main Activity XML

3) Showing and hiding the desired Toolbar on each Fragment

Hope that helps.

Comment: Simple but clever!Thanks a lot

Comment: It may cause problems, when you might need to collapse toolbar or set dynamic data into it. But yes, its simple and usefull answer.